# Total Number of Samples in Simple Random Sampling with Replacement

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

My text says that for SRSWR with samples of size $n$ being selected from $N$ units, the total number of possible samples is $N^n$.

However, when I do the following, it seemingly does not agree with the above:

> Choose samples of size $2$ from $\{A,B,C \}$. The possibles samples are
>
> $\{A,A\}, \ \{A,B\}, \ \{A,C\}, \ \{B,B\}, \  \{B,C\}, \ \{C,C\}$

Obviously this not $3^2$. What am I not understanding?

Comment: Depends on whether You consider $\{A,B\}$ and $\{B,A\}$ the same or not. If not, then $3^{2}$ it is. If yes, then $6$ it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the order matters, then we have 3 choices for the first element and 3 choices for the second. So, $3^2$ ways.

If order doesn’t matter, the answer is simply $3\choose2$$+3=6$. The $3\choose2$ is for pairs of distinct elements and the $+3$ is for pairs with same elements.